# Can't get javascript to execute in a dojo contentpane even with dojox

Tags: javascript, dojo, contentpane

I've seen other posts about getting javascript to load in a dojo contentpane by using the dojox extension.  However, I can't seem to get this to work in my scenario.

To make it easy to replicate, I'm using the example app here:
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/parserAutoRequire/

Basically I just want to be able to run javascript in one of the loaded tabs (divs).  I've tried changing dijit to dojox everywhere a contentpane is referenced by this isn't working and has been driving me mad...apart from this it's all working great!!

Any suggestions will be greatfully recieved!!!

Comment: Have you tried setting the [executeScripts](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dojox_layout_ContentPane_executeScripts) property to true?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that executeScripts is deaulted to true in a dojox contentpane, but I tried that as well just in case but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try getting an object of content pane in javascript and then executing the code on that object.

```
dijit.byId("ContentPaneId")
```

should return you the object to your content pane.

Comment: Hi Tarang.. thanks, I'll give that a try this evening and feed back results.  Does that remove the need to use dojox instead of dijit for contentpane?

Comment: I would suggest you to use dojox.layout.contentpane only. I have used the same in some of my previous work.